# How to align wrapped items differently when using Wrap?

Tags: flutter

Having this widget:

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text("a..."),
    Text("b..."),
  ],
)
```

How can I make"a..." aligned to the left and "b..." to the right? Especially when "b..." wraps to the next line, I need it to align right, while "a" is aligned left.

(It is guaranteed that there are exactly 2 children).

Comment: If you know that are two widgets is not better to use two rows one widget on each one, first aligned to left and second to right? Or it needs to be in wrap anyway?

Comment: It is not required to use `Wrap` but if there is enough space they should stay on the same line. I don't know of any widget but Wrap to achieve this?